# How do you remove the mask of the krenshar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

The [*mask of the krenshar*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/mask-of-the-krenshar/) "melds into its wearer's face and vanishes."  By that sort of description I'm not even sure if the *mask* can be physically felt anymore, let alone how to take off the *mask* once worn.

How would a wearer remove it from their own face?
Also, is it possible to remove the *mask* from someone's face while it's worn?

As far as I can tell there are no rules for this, but I might be missing something. Deactivating the *mask* or dispelling the *mask* should do *something* I'm sure, but beyond that I have no clue. I'd prefer a [rules-as-written](/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) ruling, but in one's absence, any reasonable rules-based ruling will do.

Comment: Are you asking about hostile mask-removal (ripping it off for a Scooby-style reveal), or how a person wearing the mask could remove it themselves?

Comment: Both as applicable.

Comment: Maybe [edit] the question to make that clearer, then?

Comment: I thought it was clear at first, but my brain processes things differently sometimes.  Also, some parts of it were edited already, and while it does look a bit better it did remove what I thought was the clear implication that I was asking two questions technically.  I will fix it.

Comment: @HeyICanChan  It does actually, which is another reason I thought it was clear lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [*mask of the krenshar*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/mask-of-the-krenshar/) still radiates magic even though "it melds into its wearer’s face and vanishes." So on the third round of a typical [*detect magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic) effect, the location of the *mask*'s aura is revealed.

Then a creature desiring the *mask*'s removal employs a [*dispel magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic) effect, touches the wearer's *mask*ed face, and attempts a caster level check based on the the *mask*'s caster level (typically DC 14). The creature *must* touch the *mask* because, although the *mask* "leaves the wearer’s face just as it looked before," the *mask* remains melded and, functionally, visually imperceptible. Thus a creature likely just *can't* target the *mask* with a *dispel magic* effect at range, but because he *can* touch the *dispel magic* effect's target—the *mask*—, the *dispel magic* effect, if successful, should render the *mask* inoperable for 1d4 rounds, sending it popping off the (now-former) wearer's face and ready to be scooped up by the lucky dude who dispelled it.<sup>1</sup>

Using an effect like the spell *dispel magic* in such a way may, in fact, be one of the few ways *to* dislodge a donned *mask of the krenshar*—even the wearer may struggle to remove it using conventional methods!

(The *mask* isn't the only meld-when-worn-so-it's-invisible-so-there! magic item, by the way. A wearer (and thief!) may have similar issues with, for instance, the [*eyes of the dragon*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/eyes-of-the-dragon/). The [*gloves of arrow snaring*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-of-arrow-snaring/) likely started this minitrend—dating back [as they do](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#gloves-of-arrow-snaring) to [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) and those adapted from *at least* [adnd-2e](/questions/tagged/adnd-2e)'s *gloves of missile snaring* (*Encyclopedia Magica* 544), yet the *gloves*—even in *Pathfinder*—only ever *seemed* to meld. The *Magica* goes so far as to say its *gloves* are noticeable to viewers within 5 ft. of the wearer. I suspect that later authors have read this *seeming* melding as a *literal* melding, leaving us where we are now.)

Alternatively, the GM may rule that the wearer of the *mask* can remove it whenever he likes, and, perhaps, that others can remove the wearer's *mask* normally if they know of the *mask*'s presence… or even if they don't by clutching at the wearer's face! In such cases, the GM's essentially ruled that the *mask*'s melding property is just flowery exposition that mollifies a potential wearer who is—for whatever reason—reluctant to roam around town wearing a leather cat mask.

Hence, under such a ruling, the *mask* continues its normal existence, and it functions—despite its melding and despite its imperceptibility—like a normal mask, in much the same way each worn magic item need not explicitly *say* that the worn magic item can be removed in the typical fashion.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Also see [Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) on Target or Targets: "Some spells have a target or targets. You cast these spells on creatures or objects, as defined by the spell itself. You must be able to see or touch the target, and you must specifically choose that target."

Comment: Wouldn't the wearer simply *will* for the ability to deactivate be enough? If it isn't [cursed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items/) anyway. My understanding is that simply wearing is not enough to activate it, it must be identified and the wearer know about the item's abilities (similar to a bandana of int).

Comment: @ShadowKras You're right that the answer was taking a literal view. Added an alternative for easier removal based on precedent.